# Prove that $\left|\frac{x^3y^3}{9x^4+y^4}\right| \le \frac{x^2+y^2}{6}$

Tags: inequality, absolute-value, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I need to prove that: $$\left|\frac{x^3y^3}{9x^4+y^4}\right| \le \frac{x^2+y^2}{6}$$

I am new to inequalities so I only tried C-S and  AM-GM but none of those work.

Any hints on how to proceed here?.

Comment: Hint:  By A.M-G.M inequality $9x^4+y^4 \geq 6(x^2+y^2) $ and $2xy \leq x^2+y^2 $

Comment: Your first inequality is not true @L-- try $x<\frac{1}{3},y=0$ to see why

Comment: I am extremely sorry... It was a typo. (AM-GM inequality does not give us such expression either). It should have been $x^2y^2$ in place of $x^2+y^2$.

Comment: It is still not correct, adding parentheses didn't help. Unless your edit is something else.

Comment: If $x,y\geq 1$ then it is easily seen to be true.

Comment: @CiaránÓRaghaillaigh, however, the inequality of my post is true for numbers $<1$. For instance, try $x=0.1$ and $y=0.2$

Comment: Corrected hint: By AM-GM inequality, $(9x^4+y^4) \geq 6x^2y^2$ and $2xy \leq (x^2+y^2)$

Comment: @L-- you should write $(x^2 + y^2) \geq 2|xy|$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $y=mx$, then the inequality becomes $$m^4-6m^3+10m^2+9 \ge 0 ~~~~~~(1)$$
Let $f(m)=m^4-6m^3+10m^2+9 \implies f'(m)=4m^3-18m^2+20m=0, m=0,2,5/2$,
$f(m)$ has min at $m=0, 5/2$ and max at $m=2$, but $f(0), f(2), f(5/2)>0.$
So $f(m)>0, \forall m \in R$. Equivalently, $f(m)=0$ does not have any real root. Hence the inequality is proved and the equality does not hold.

Answer (score 3):

$(9x^4 + y^4)(x^2 + y^2)\ \ge\ (3x^3 + y^3)^2\ \ge\ |6x^3y^3|$

Answer (score 3):

For $xy=0$ it's obvious.

But for $xy\neq0$ by AM-GM we obtain:
$$\left|\frac{x^3y^3}{9x^4+y^4}\right|\leq\frac{|x^3y^3|}{2\sqrt{9x^4y^4}}=\frac{|xy|}{6}\leq\frac{\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}}{6}\leq\frac{x^2+y^2}{6}.$$